# react-native doctor : Android SDK - Versions found: N/A Windows 10

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I am currently trying to install Fleetbase Navigator App using Android Studio on my Windows machine from github repository

Here is the URL: https://github.com/fleetbase/navigator-app.git

I have installed Android Studio in my laptop as well as Android SDK Tools. I also have set the path to SDK installation folder and command line tools. But when I tried to build the application project, the terminal show an error output which shows

[Error from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rG2K.png)

From this, I understand that there is something wrong with the Android Development Environment (note that I have already installed SDK Build Tools, SDK Platforms, SDK Command Line Tools and APIs for each SDK Platforms and set the path in system variables) so I tried to confirm the error using

```
react-native doctor
```

Refer the images

[React-Native Doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfMQA.png)

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiB4s.png)

Is there something I missed that might be causing the error. I also used doctor to fix the error but it still does not fix my problem